# padding errors in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, padding

I am running my code first time on Visual studio. Among hundreds of warnings that have popped up, two are being treated as errors which are pointed to some issues in time.h.

The first warning is

```
     Warning    C4820   '_timespec64': '4' bytes padding added after data member '_timespec64::tv_nsec'
```

which points to the following code in time.h

```
     struct _timespec64
     {
     __time64_t tv_sec;
     long       tv_nsec;
     };
```

The second warning is

```
     Warning    C4820   'timespec': '4' bytes padding added after data member 'timespec::tv_nsec'
```

which points to the following part of time.h

```
    #ifndef _CRT_NO_TIME_T
    struct timespec
    {
       time_t tv_sec;  // Seconds - >= 0
       long   tv_nsec; // Nanoseconds - [0, 999999999]
    };
    #endif
```

What is this padding referring to and how can this be resolved?

Comment: This needs a [mcve].

Comment: Standard headers that come with MSVC are not clean at warning level 4. Trying to compile with `/W4` or `/Wall` is essentially hopeless.

Comment: I would be as worried about the hundreds of warnings as about the two being treated as errors. Even if all of those warnings are false positives, how would you spot a legitimate warning if it were to crop up in that mess?

Comment: the other warnings seem unrelated to me

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], the version of Visual Studio you are using, and the solution configuration and platform? I am using Version 16.8.3 and do not see these warnings no matter the settings I choose.

Answer (score 2):

When you define some struct student like this,

```
{  
  char a; // 1 byte  
  char b; // 1 byte  
  int c;  // 4 bytes   
}
```

You expect memory arrangement like this.

```
... [a] [b] [c] [c] [c] [c] [ ] [ ] ...
```

The 4-bytes can be accessed at a time as we are considering the 32-bit architecture. The problem is that in one CPU cycle, one byte of char a, one byte of char b, and 2 bytes of int c can be accessed. We will not face any problem while accessing the char a and char b as both the variables can be accessed in one CPU cycle, but we will face the problem when we access the int c variable as 2 CPU cycles are required to access the value of the 'c' variable. In the first CPU cycle, the first two bytes are accessed, and in the second cycle, the other two bytes are accessed.

Suppose we do not want to access the 'a' and 'b' variable, we only want to access the variable 'c', which requires two cycles. The variable 'c' is of 4 bytes, so it can be accessed in one cycle also, but in this scenario, it is utilizing 2 cycles. This is an unnecessary wastage of CPU cycles. Due to this reason, the structure padding concept was introduced to save the number of CPU cycles. The structure padding is done automatically by the compiler. Now, we will see how structure padding is done.

```
... [a] [b] [ ] [ ] [c] [c] [c] [c] ...
```

In order to achieve the structure padding, an empty row is created on the left, as shown in the above diagram, and the two bytes which are occupied by the 'c' variable on the left are shifted to the right. So, all the four bytes of 'c' variable are on the right. Now, the 'c' variable can be accessed in a single CPU cycle. After structure padding, the total memory occupied by the structure is 8 bytes (1 byte+1 byte+2 bytes+4 bytes), which is greater than the previous one. Although the memory is wasted in this case, the variable can be accessed within a single cycle.

---

I assume that the size of a long type in your system is 4 bytes and the size of a time type is 8 bytes. In that case, memory allocation will happen like below.

```
... [t] [t] [t] [t] [t] [t] [t] [t] [l] [l] [l] [l] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] ...
    [---------------- structure type memory area ---------------- ]
```

You can check it `sizeof(_timespec64)`. Then it will return 16.

---

To avoid it, You have to change your visual studio preference.

```
Project right click
-> Property
   -> Project settings
      -> Configuration Properties
         -> c/c++ general
            -> Treat warnings as errors
```

Comment: @JaMiT is C4820 just a warning not a error? Right?

Comment: Normally I would think C4820 is just a warning, but according to the question you are answering: *"two [warnings] are being treated as errors"*.

Comment: yes, visual studio says they are being treated as errors

Comment: @cleanplay You have to change visutal studio configuration like this.
Project right click
-> Property
   -> Project settings
      -> Configuration Properties
         -> c/c++ general
            -> Treat warnings as errors (UNCHECK)

Comment: +1. Just one thing to mention is that OP seems to be using a 64-bit system - if it were a 32-bit system, there would be no need for padding since 8+4 bytes are a multiple of 4 bytes. Oh, and it's worth noting that MSVC(which OP is probably using) uses 4 bytes for `long`, contrary to gcc or clang which use 8 bytes. Thanks for the nicely visualized answer!